# Retrieve post modified date for specific post by post ID

Tags: functions, templates

I am looking to use the 'the_modified_date' function to display the date and time of a **specific post** has been modified. This information will appear in the header of our website on every single page.

How would I go about completing this?

I can use  to get the title, and was hoping there would be a way just as easy to display that posts date and time.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Place this code snippet put in **function.php**, this should give you what you need.

```
function my_theme_wp_title( $title, $sep ) {
    global $post;

    /* my other title cases */

    //get post's modified date
    $m_date = get_the_modified_date();

    //concatenate the current title with the date string, using the separator to be more clear
    $title .= $sep . " " . $m_date;

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'my_theme_wp_title', 10, 2 );
```

Basically we add our custom function hooked to the **wp_title** filter, thus altering **wp_title** function, giving us the flexibility to add custom logic in the title display.

Cheers!

Comment: Answers should be more that just a bunch of code. Please file an [edit] and add an explanation to how your code works and how it should be used and where it should be used. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Kindly refer below :

```
    <?php if (get_the_modified_time() != get_the_time()) : ?>

    <p>Posted: <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> at <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?>, 
    Last Updated: <?php the_modified_time('F j, Y'); ?> at <?php the_modified_time('g:i a'); ?></p>

<?php else: ?>

    <p>Posted: <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> at <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?></p>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Just a note on the update, an explanation where the code should go and how it works will be nice. Remember, this answer should be a reference for others aswell, not just the OP